# Magnetic vector potential of an infinite wire

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge

Using the integral $$A=\frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{I \vec{dl}}{r}$$ for calculating magnetic vector potential of an infinite wire we get $$A = \left(\frac{\mu_0 I}{4 \pi}\right) \ln(\sec \theta + \tan \theta)$$ which diverges when the limits are from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. We can get around this by solving $B=\nabla \times A$ which gives us a finite answer.

My question is why does the first formula fail for this problem and is it fixable?

Comment: The integral formula cannot be used when the current extends all the way to infinity. This is also the case in electrostatics: if you try to compute the electric potential of an infinite wire using the integral representation you get a divergent integral as well.

Comment: The integral formula is a solution to Poisson's equation in three dimensions given the boundary condition that the potential vanishes at infinity; as such it cannot be applied in such a case where the current distribution is infinite. The corresponding formula for $V$ in electrostatics has the same restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the formula fails is because you have computed the integral wrong. The coulomb gauge does work, it by definition MUST.

The equation for A is

$\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec{A}) - \nabla^2 \vec{A} = -\mu_0 \vec{J}$

In the coulomb gauge $\nabla \cdot \vec{A} $= 0

This means the equation for A reduces to

$\nabla^2 \vec{A} = \mu_{0} \vec{J}$

Now...

The standard solution to A in the context of line currents is

$A(\vec{r})=\iiint \frac{\mu_{0}I}{4\pi} \frac{\vec{dl}}{|r-r'|}$

Notice that this is basically the same equation for the scalar potential V in the context of electrostatics. Notice also that when computing the electrostatic potential where infinity is NOT our reference frame, there is a +c on this integral. And when infinity is taken to be our reference point, the plus C vanishes. In the context of electrostatics, the gradient of a constant is zero so it doesnt change the physics, much like in magnetostatics the curl of a constant is zero. Meaning the B field is the same. What does this mean? Well this means that in the coulomb gauge I can have a non divergence potential. This doesn't matter, as I will prove to you now that even the divergent one can still yield a correct result.

For a wire in the z plain, of infinite length. Current I, using cylindrical coordinates

Where I am evaluating my point at $<\rho,\theta,0>$
And the wire is located on the z axis, using the variable z' to specify the location of my wire. The integral I would have to solve is:

$A(\vec{r})=\iiint_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_{0}I}{4\pi} \frac{ \hat k dz'}{\sqrt{(\rho)^2+(z')^2}}$

Note that Since the wire is infinite, I will be choosing the location I am evaluating the B field to  be z=0 ( I don't have to , but later I will use symettry to say that it is 2x the integral from 0 to infinity, and to be honest, I'm not sure if I can say this when z isn't in the center, I suspect I can ,since the wire is infinity, but for now I'll stick with z=0)

To solve this i will need to make the substitution

$z'= \rho tan(\phi)$

$dz'=\rho sec^2(\phi) d\phi$

$A(\vec{r})=\iiint_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_{0}I}{4\pi} \frac{\hat k \rho sec^2(\phi) d\phi  }{\sqrt{(\rho)^2+(\rho tan(\phi))^2}}$

$A(\vec{r})=\iiint_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi} \frac{ \hat k \rho sec^2(\phi) d\phi  }{\sqrt{(\rho)^2+\rho^2 tan^2(\phi)}}$

$A(\vec{r})=\iiint_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi} \frac{\hat k \rho sec^2(\phi) d\phi  }{\sqrt{(\rho)^2(1+tan^2(\phi))}}$

$A(\vec{r})=\iiint_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi} \frac{\hat k \rho sec^2(\phi) d\phi  }{(\rho)(sec(\phi))}$

$A(\vec{r})=\iiint_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}  \hat k  sec(\phi) d\phi  $

which is a nice and simple integration

=$ \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}    ln|sec(\phi) + tan(\phi)|\hat k$

Evaluated from -$\infty$ to $\infty$

Due to symmetry this is the same as 2x the integral from 0 to $\infty$

$\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi}    ln|sec(\phi) + tan(\phi)|\hat k$

Evaluated from 0 to $\infty$

now here is where you have gone slightly wrong, we need to change the bounds to be in a form that is $\phi$

$z' = \rho tan(\phi)$

When z' =0, it is clear that $tan(\phi)$ is zero,
Drawing a triangle, with angle $\phi$ we can also see that $ln|sec(\phi)|$ is also zero.  Meaning the contribution is zero. (

Now let's look at the more "tricky bound"

naively plugging in infinity, and then saying that tan(phi) is infinity, doing the same for sec, would also naively get you infinity

THIS IS WRONG firstly, we can clearly see that,as plugging in infinity to $\rho$ wouldn't make A infinity... the inside of the log actually comes out to be $\sqrt(2) + 1$

To evaluate this easily

draw a triangle,

$Tan(\phi)= \frac{z'}{\rho}$

$Sec(\phi)= \frac{\sqrt{(\rho)^2+(z')^2}}{\rho}$

Thus our integral evaluates to

$\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi}   ln| \frac{\sqrt{(\rho)^2+(z')^2}}{\rho} + \frac{z'}{\rho}| \hat k $

Simplifying,

$\frac{\mu_0 I }{2\pi}   ln| \sqrt{1+(\frac{z'}{\rho})^2} + \frac{z'}{\rho}| \hat k $

Here we have it in a form with our "missing" variables! The integral is divergent, that is no problem! We can STILL obtain our fields.

Computing the curl in cylindrical coordinates is easy, since it only has a z component, so the curl is

$B = \frac{dA}{d\rho} \hat \theta$

Now take the limit as z' goes to infinity!

doing so, gets you ALOT AND ALOT of messy algebra and limits! But if you go through it carefully, you DO  get the correct magnetic field that

$\vec{B(\rho)} = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi\rho} \hat \theta$

Yes it is a pain in the a** but even this divergent integral gives you the correct B field with careful mathematical treatment! The coulomb gauge STILL works( It is a "fun" exercise to do, give it a try)

Comment: Can anyone explain to me if what i have done  is correct. I have gone through the curl and I do get the correct B field yet... my intuition says that when rho is infinity, A should vanish! But IT DOESNT, can anyone see if it actually SHOULD? Perhaps not

Comment: As per my answer to your other question, you are using the method of [Green's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) in your "standard solution." When you learn about them, you will find that in order to derive the $1/4\pi|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|$ which appears in your expression, you make the assumption that the charge distribution and solution vanish as $\rho\rightarrow \infty$. For an infinite line charge, this assumption fails, and so we need to apply the boundary condition at some finite $\rho_0$ instead; this yields an alternate Green's function, and when we go [...]

Comment: I also have some doubts that the evaluation of the integrated function at zero always zero, as taking the limit where rho is zero doesnt give me zero?

Comment: [...] through the calculation which I describe in [my answer to your other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/684045/1568950), you find that $\mathbf A \propto \log(\rho/\rho_0)$ (thus satisfying our boundary condition) with no divergent integrals in sight. The reason the curl of your formally divergent expression works is in some sense a lucky break, which relies on the properties of the logarithm. The same thing would not occur if you tried to solve for the magnetic field of an infinite sheet of charge, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that last comment, as neither $\mathbf B$ nor $\mathbf A$ should be zero (or indeed, even exist) at $\rho=0$ due to the presence of the very singular current distribution there.

Comment: I'll try to do the same for a infinite sheet at some point and see if I can get the correct fields :)

Comment: And I meant my assumption that evaluating the integrated function at z'=0, must give me 0 isn't strictly true at the limit rho goes to zero.

Comment: I havent done the infinite sheet yet, however i think that I will be able to still obtain the fields from it. as consider the magnetic vector potential. this potential is used to derive the actual B field. the B field formula  DOES still work for infinite sheets and infinite lines of current. I understand that the derivation of A requires that it vanishes at infinity however because B is obtained from A, and B still works for infinite situations, then I have a feeling I CAN obtain the fields even in the situation where A doesnt go to zero, regardless of whether or not "A" is actually valid",

Comment: I need to learn greens functions to understand it, as it has very much peaked my interest into WHY i was able to solve for B even if the A formula "isnt valid". but  also even in your solution that you have derived in the other post where the boundary conditions is that it doesnt go to infinity, When RHO in your solution goes to infinity, the potential doesnt vanish? as its log(infinity). im probably misunderstanding something about this thought though as I still am learning

Comment: After some thought, I agree. The point I have been making is that trying to apply that integral formula is a misapplication of the Green’s function approach because it ignores the fact that Green’s functions have boundary conditions built into them - which is why the integral doesn’t converge. Doing it correctly yields the actual vector potential. As you say, a related approach *does* work for the magnetic field, so throwing away infinities and differentiating under the integral sign yields the correct result for $B$, but you should understand how Green’s functions actually work because […]

Comment: […] this kind of “happy accident” is not universal. And yes, in my solution the potential doesn’t go to zero at infinity - that’s the point. It goes to zero at $\rho_0$, because *that* is the boundary condition which is baked into my green’s function. Trying to set it to zero at infinity is doomed to fail, because it does not have a well-defined limit there, which is why integrating against the wrong greens function yields infinity instead of something well-defined.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so lets start with the basics, the answer we are expecting is given by:
$$\vec B= \frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r} \hat e_\theta$$
Which is from Ampere's law.

From this we can kind of backwards engineer, to show that:
$$\vec A=-\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi} \ln(r) \hat e_z$$
would work as the potential.

The reason I don't think your method works is because you are forcing the coulomb gauge (i.e. $\nabla \cdot \vec A=0$) onto the system and in this situation the integral diverges.  In other words we have the freedom to chose $\vec A$ since:
$$\vec A'=\vec A+\nabla(\phi)$$
For some function $\phi$ both satisfy: 
$$\vec B=\nabla \times \vec A=\nabla \times \vec A'$$
It happens that your choice of $\vec A$ is not well defined in this case, i.e. the coulomb gauge doesn't work.

Comment: The vector potential written here is correct, but the statement that the Coulomb gauge doesn't work is incorrect. Just compute $\vec\nabla \cdot\vec A$ to see that it vanishes. The expression for $\vec A$ as an integral involving the current cannot be used because the wire extends to infinity.

Comment: The coulomb gauge does work, by definition this must be a valid solution. Actually doing the computation yourself. does yield an infinite result. There is absolutely nothing wrong with that. As  this just means potential is defined at zero at infinity, but because there are sources at infinity it diverges. IN FACT in the coulomb gauge we can obtain non divergent solution, like the one that you have written down. This is still in the coulomb gauge, yet the standard formula for A in the coulomb gauge is a PARTICULAR SOLUTION where A is zero at infinity. There are infinitely many

Comment: Vector potentials in the coulomb gauge that satisfy the condition that the curl is B, as grad (v+c) is the same as grad(v) its just that the standard formula chooses C such  that it diverges. Divergence isn't a problem as it just means your reference point is particular value. The main reason I assume you didn't see this is because the OP'S solution contained NO variables! That is because he computed the integral wrong! I'll post an actual solution to this integral in a minute where you can take the curl of this and get the B field

Answer (score 1):

Below picture shows an infinite wire and an imaginary loop for calculating the vector potential super much easier.

[image]

$$
\begin{align}
B &= \nabla \times A \\
\iint B \cdot \mathrm{d}a &= \oint A \cdot \mathrm{d}l \\
\int_a^b \frac{\mu l}{2 \pi r} L \, \mathrm{d}r &= AL \\
A &= \frac{\mu l}{2 \pi} \ln{\frac{b}{a}} Z
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please type the math with [MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It makes it easier for people on all devices to read it. Also, it would help if you could include a more detailed annotation.

Comment: Welcome to SE.Physics!  I converted the equations in your picture to $\mathrm{\TeX}$ (which is implemented through MathJax here), as @Chair recommended.  If you try to [edit] your post, you can see the $\mathrm{\TeX}$ code to pick up on how it's done and make any changes that might improve the answer.  In general, you can write `$x$` to render $x$.

Comment: A here changes with distance from the wire, how did you take it out of the line integral?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments by Chriss, Y and J. Murray, the formula assumes that the zero Dirichlete boundary condition at $\bf r=\infty$ holds in 3-dimensions; however this assumption is no longer valid in the case of infinite wire. Let us turn back to the original formula that computes $\bf A$ for any three dimensional current distribution $\bf J$
$$\mathbf A=\int_V \frac{\mu_0 \mathbf J}{4\pi|\mathbf r|}dv$$
where $|\mathbf r|$ is the Euclidean distance of source point and field point. This is the solution to $\nabla^2 \mathbf A = \mu_0 \mathbf J$ with $\mathbf A(|\mathbf r|=\infty)=0$. This solution is indeed a linear combination of the fundamental solution of Poisson equation $G^*(|\mathbf r|)$ that is written as follows,
$$\mathbf A=\int_V \mu_0 \mathbf J G^*(|\mathbf r|)dv$$
$$G^*(|\mathbf r|)=\frac{1}{4\pi|\mathbf r|}$$
The fundamental solution is the solution to the Dirac source distribution or in a physical sense to a point charge. The above $G^*(|\mathbf r|)$ is valid for three dimensional space, but for two-dimensional it is as follows,
$$G^*(|\mathbf r|)=-\frac{\ln(|\mathbf r|)}{2\pi}$$
In the above solution, the boundary condition $\mathbf A(|\mathbf r|=\infty)=0$ is only defined for two-dimensions, in other words, potential decays in $x-y$ space at infinity but in $z$ direction, potential is constant. Thus for two-dimensional, we have,
$$\mathbf A=\int_S \mu_0 \mathbf J\frac{-\ln(|\mathbf r|)}{2\pi}ds$$
where $S$ is the surface cross section of current. For an infinitesimal wire, current is concentrated in an infinitesimally small area; thereby, volume current density is Dirac distributed. Replacing $\mathbf J = I \delta$ and putting in the above, yields,
$$\mathbf A=\int_S \mu_0 I \delta\frac{-\ln(|\mathbf r|)}{2\pi}ds
= \mu_0 I \frac{-\ln(|\mathbf r|)}{2\pi}$$
We could have ommited the last computation, as you can see the fundamental solution in two-dimensional case is the solution to our problem (multiplied by $\mu_0 I$). This is because an infinitesimal wire in two dimensions has Dirac distribution and the solution of which, by definition, is exactly the fundamental solution.