# Gauge choice and validity of Magnetic vector potential for an infinitely straight wire

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge

Consider an infinitely thin, infinitely long wire,

Using the standard formula for the magnetic vector potential, we obtain the result that the magnetic vector potential is infinity,( with no variables)

And takes the form that $A$ is proportional to
$$ \ln|\sec(\theta)+\tan(\theta)| $$ evaluated at $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$

This is because we have specifically used the gauge choice $\nabla \cdot \vec{A} = 0$ in order to find the standard formula.

I have also seen that the formula

$$\vec A=-\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi} \ln(r) \hat e_z$$

Would ALSO work as a valid potential function.

So my question is this:

What gauge choice do I need to evoke in order to obtain a valid formula for the magnetic vector potential that does NOT diverge for an infinitely thin, and infinitely long wire(or how to find it another way)

I also don't understand why there isn't at least SOME variables that I can take the curl of, to find the correct magnetic field, As it technically IS a perfect solution to the equation

$$\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec{A}) - \nabla^2 \vec{A} = -\mu_{0} \vec{J}$$

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/550057/50583

Comment: I am aware that potential functions don't need to be zero at infinity,  we can choose any origin of potential we would like, no matter if the distribution extends to infinity. Its just that if it DOES extend to infinity. By  defining potential zero there would cause the potential to be infinity at every other point in space. That's not really what I'm asking. Atleast in the formula for the e.g electric potential of an infinite line charge we can still obtain the correct fields from it as they contain variables to take the gradient of

Comment: The coulomb gauge is still valid for this, however by evaluating it, you actually lose part of the answer. Take for example an infinite line charge,  evaluating this using the definition of potential, in line integral form. Gives it to you in a form where you can input your potential. Choosing infinity to be your reference causes the integral to obviously diverge for non infinity evaluations. But! We still have a part of the integral containing our variables such that we can obtain the correct fields from. however! Using  an equivelant formula for the potential evaluated at infinity

Comment: (The formula in e.g volume integral form) using the same distribution as a infinite line charge, you obviously get the same result that the potential is infinity  everywhere other than infinity. however in THIS FORM you do NOT have variables that you can take the gradient of!

Comment: however! VERY CAREFUL mathematical treatment of the line charge integral. AND the integral in my original post, CAN extract the finite part. Look at what I post in the answer section. Can you help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation we're trying to solve is
$$\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf A) - \nabla^2 \mathbf A = -\mu_0 \mathbf J$$
From a mathematical standpoint, an infinitely long, infinitely thin wire does not constitute a well-defined current density in the usual sense - rather, it would take the form of a delta distribution $\mathbf J = I \delta(x) \delta(y)\hat z$ in cartesian coordinates.

The easiest way to handle this is to use cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ and solve the equation
$$-\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf A) - \nabla^2 \mathbf A = 0$$
on the domain $(r,\theta,z)\in (0,\infty)\times[0,2\pi) \times (-\infty,\infty)$ subject to some boundary conditions that we'll get to in a moment.   Choosing the Coulomb gauge condition $\nabla \cdot \mathbf A=0$ yields the familiar Laplace equation, and taking advantage of the cylindrical symmetry of the problem (so $\partial_\theta,\partial_z \rightarrow 0$) yields the fairly straightforward equation
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial r}\right)=0 \implies r \frac{\mathbf A}{\partial r} = \mathbf c \implies \mathbf A = \mathbf c \ln(r/r_0)$$
for some unknown vector $\mathbf c$. $r_0$ is simply an integration constant, and can be chosen to be any value you wish. The subsequent magnetic field is given by
$$\mathbf B= \nabla \times \mathbf A = -\frac{c_z}{r} \hat \theta + \frac{c_\phi}{r}\left(\ln(r/r_0) + 1\right)\hat z$$

The aforementioned boundary condition is that if consider an arbitrary curve $\mathbf r(t)$ which encloses the wire and compute $\oint \mathbf B \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf r$, then we will obtain $\mu_0 I$.  After a bit of work, we find that in order for this to be true for *arbitrary* curves, $c_\phi=0$ (otherwise the result of the line integral would be curve-dependent) and $c_z = - \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi}$, and so we finally obtain

$$\mathbf A = -\frac{\mu_o I}{2\pi} \ln(r/r_0) \hat z \implies \mathbf B =  \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r} \hat \theta \tag{$\star$}$$

---

The "standard solution" referenced by the OP and others is a special case of a Green's function solution.  Briefly, the underlying idea goes as follows. Consider a differential equation for an unknown function $u(\mathbf r)$ of the form
$$L\big[u\big](\mathbf r) = f(\mathbf r)$$
(where $L$ is a linear differential operator) on some region $D$ with boundary $\partial D$, where $u$ is subject to e.g. Dirichlet boundary conditions on $\partial D$. If we first solve the equation
$$L[G](\mathbf r) = \delta(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')$$
where $G$ is subject to the same boundary conditions, then we find that the correct solution to the original equation is given by
$$u(\mathbf r) = \int_D \mathrm d^n r' \ f(\mathbf r') G(\mathbf r;\mathbf r')$$

As an example, one might consider the 3D Laplacian with $D$ the ball of radius $R$ centered at the origin, and Dirichlet boundary conditions on $\partial D$. It turns out that the correct solution is
$$G_R(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') = \frac{1}{4\pi|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|} - \frac{R/r'}{4\pi|\mathbf r - \frac{R^2}{r'^2}\mathbf r'|}$$
which can be seen to vanish when $|\mathbf r|=R$.  Furthermore, this $G_R$ has a well-defined limit as $R\rightarrow \infty$, and taking that limit yields the so-called *free space* Green's function $G_\infty(\mathbf r,\mathbf r')= 1/4\pi|\mathbf r- \mathbf r'|$. **Note that there is no reason to expect this limit to exist in general.**

Since the problem of an infinite line charge is mathematically equivalent to that of a 2D point charge, consider the 2D version of the example above.  In this case, it turns out that the Green's function is

$$G_R(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') = \frac{1}{2\pi}\log|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'| - \frac{1}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{r'}{R}|\mathbf r-\frac{R^2}{r'^2} \mathbf r'|\right)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{r^2-2\mathbf r\cdot \mathbf r' + r'^2}{\frac{r'^2}{R^2}r^2 - 2\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf r' + R^2}}\right)$$

Observe that $G_R$ does **not** have a well-defined limit as $R\rightarrow \infty$. As a result, it is *not possible* to solve $\nabla^2G = \delta(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')$ subject to the boundary condition that $G\rightarrow 0$ as $|\mathbf r|\rightarrow \infty$; you know this already, in the form of the fact that the electrostatic potential due to an infinite line charge diverges logarithmically as $|\mathbf r|\rightarrow \infty$. Instead, we are forced to solve this equation on a finite domain - say, a disk of radius $R$. If apply this solution to your problem, we find that

$$\mathbf A = \int_D \mathrm d^2 r' [\mu_0 I \delta(\mathbf r')\hat z] G_R(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi} \ln\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)\hat z$$

This gives us a nice interpretation for the integration constant $r_0$ in $(\star)$. If we want to apply Dirichlet boundary conditions to the equation $\nabla^2 \mathbf A = \mu_0 I\delta(x)\delta(y)\hat z$, then we cannot do so at infinity like we can in the case of a 3D point charge. Instead, we pick a finite disk of radius $r_0$ and impose our Dirichlet conditions on the boundary of the disk, and that $r_0$ appears in the solution to enforce this condition.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have 2 questions: I Completely understand why the magnetic vector potential has no z, or $\theta$ dependence, and subsequently laplaces equation reduces to the equation that you have written down. I also understand how to solve it. However can you explain to me why using the standard formula for poissons equation, when the source function is input to be zero, that we get the answer to be 0? As they should give the same answer. I don't know how to solve poisons equation yet, so I have to only guess that the standard formula is for no boundary conditions

Comment: and don't worry about the second question :)

Comment: I will have ago later at finding the constants of integration myself :), i don't suppose it would be easier to compute the general path in another coordinate system than cartesian?

Comment: Or specific boundary condition*

Comment: @jensenpaull I'm not entirely sure I understand the question about getting $0$ from Poisson's equation.  However, I would note that when we solve differential equations whose source terms are delta distributions and other such things, one generic procedure is to solve the *homogeneous* equation away from the singularity (in this case, for $r\in (0,\infty$ rather than $r\in [0,\infty)$ ) and then determine integration constants by applying some variant of the Stokes' theorem. For example, one can find the electrostatic potential due to a point charge by solving $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ [...]

Comment: [...] on the region $\mathbb R^3-\{\mathbf 0\}$ (from which the origin has been cut out) and then applying the divergence theorem and requiring that the flux through any closed surface containing the origin is $q/\epsilon_0$. The idea behind the approach is that the potential is going to be poorly-behaved at the location of the singular source term, so we should solve the equation where the source is well-behaved and then integrate over the singular region to obtain a well-defined "boundary condition" (though of course, it's not really a boundary condition).

Comment: $$ \vec{A}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int d^3\vec{r}' \frac{\vec{j}(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}$$ poisons equation can be solved using this, which is the solution to the equation $\nabla^2 \vec{A} = \mu_0 \vec{J} $.When $\vec{J} = 0$, this reduces to the homogenous equation that has the general solution you have described. Yet plugging in $ \vec{J}= 0$ into the solution to poissons equation is $ \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int d^3\vec{r}' \frac{0}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} $= 0 which seems to indicate that this solution is a PARTICULAR solution to poissons equation and not the general solution.

Comment: What is it about the derivation of this formula that excludes the possibility of the constants you have described , when solving it more directly

Comment: Or, is the solution to poissons equation when J =0  actually zero , and the  logic behind saying it has no theta or z dependence the reason we get a non zero answer ( or atleast the possibility that it is non zero)

Comment: @jensenpaull The solution to $\nabla^2 \mathbf A=0$ *on all of $\mathbb R^3$* - subject to the assumptions of cylindrical symmetry - is indeed zero.  However, this is not the case here. From one point of view, this is because the current density $\mathbf J\neq 0$ for $r=0$ (at the location of the wire); from the point of view I adopted in my answer, this is because I have cut out $r=0$ from the domain under consideration. This gives me extra freedom which takes the form of integration constants, which I determine via some integral theorem or another (Stokes, in this case).

Comment: Yeah I get you. Substituting j=0 into the equation isn't indicative of the situation as its only zero for r=/ 0,however... the solution that you have determined using laplaces equation, and then via your boundary conditions,  are basically solving poissons equation where j is a 2 dimensional Dirac function. Your final solution has some arbitrary constant in, even when you input the "boundary conditions" i am perfectly okay with that since there are infinite potentials, even in the specific coulomb gauge that satisfy the condition that the curl is B.  But in the standard formula for solving -..

Comment: Poissons equation, it seems to indicate that this is a SPECIAL solution, where $r_{0}$ is -infinity. Which is a particular solution. Still a valid one i might add. But what about the standard formula for poissons equation imposes the condition on $r_{0}$ that it is a specific value. When in reality. Even in the coulomb gauge, it could take many values

Comment: As solving the poisson equation formula, for a 2d Dirac gets you an answer of infinity. Which is a solution but aparticular one

Comment: I would assume that the standard poisson equation formula is a particular solution where the magnetic vector potential is defined to be zero at infinity

Comment: @jensenpaull I have substantially updated my answer to address your follow-up, and to treat the "standard solution" you refer to. Tl;dr that solution is in fact not appropriate or viable in this case because the infinite line charge extends out to infinity, rendering the built-in boundary condition (that the solution vanishes at infinity) impossible. A restriction of the domain is needed, which results in a modification of the Green's function, which ultimately yields the right solution.

Comment: Why wouldn't the standard formula not work? As I have actually obtained the correct fields from it!, I don't know about green functions yet, so that is something I will learn and re read your edit! Although, straight off the bat, I can say that the conclusion you have drawn is wrong. Atleast in the context of finding the fields, I'll link my solution in another post here

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222343/magnetic-vector-potential-of-an-infinite-wire/684200#684200

Comment: However do you mind having alot at the question i posed in the comment of that answer. As I feel I have gone wrong somewhere. Yet I actually obtained the correct fields when taking the limit

Comment: @jensenpaull The "standard formula" doesn't work because the resulting integral diverges, as you even say in your answer.  The *reason* the integral diverges - as I say in my answer here - is because the "standard formula" is a Green's function (whether you know it or not) which **automatically includes** the boundary condition that the solution vanishes at infinity, **which is not possible to satisfy** in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is the best philosophy, but the moment delta distributions are included in treatments that usually assumes nice properties of functions (even assumes functions), I would not bother too much with somewhat surprising infinities...

As for the question, idk if that is what you are looking for, but the given current density is
$$ \vec{j} = I \delta(x)\delta(y) \vec{e}_z$$
For given $\vec{j}$ to find $A$ one just needs to integrate this, as you know from the general solution of static current densities
$$ \vec{A}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int d^3\vec{r}' \frac{\vec{j}(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}$$
The physically sensible quantity is $\vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A} $, and inserting this above, gives instantly the Biot-savart law. In this case $A$ diverges, but $B \propto 1/r$ as it should be. Notice that $B$ was only calculable, because the order of integration and curl were interchanged (which again is not rly rigorous). And I think for you to yield a usable expression for $A$ you need to again, change some ordering. Introducing
$$ \vec{j}_{\Lambda} = \vec{j} \Theta(\Lambda - |z|)$$
The corresponding vector potential $A_{\Lambda}$ is finite and is precisely of the solution you ve uploaded the picture of. For this finite $A_{\Lambda}$ you can consider
$$ \vec{A}_{\Lambda} \mapsto \vec{A}_{\Lambda} + \nabla (-z\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi}\ln(\Lambda))  = \vec{e}_z \frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi} \ln\left(\frac{1}{\rho} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{\Lambda^2} + \frac{1}{\rho^2}}\right)$$

Now you can take your limit $\Lambda \to \infty$. Here, again, what you kind of have to take as a given, is that you can change the order of gauge transforming and limits, etc., but I think if you are willing to accept delta distributions as inputs, you need to relax further rigour down the road...

Comment: The reason I was exploring this is because the infinities make it very hard to find the magnetic field energy as we need A to find it, and the standard formula for magnetic energy derived in the context of magnetostatics requires that the surface integral of AxB  to be zero, but I don't think that it is for this case. Could you give me a link on what this method for solving divergent integrals is called so I can learn further :), it seems very elegant that we can extract the finite part of a seemingly divergent integral

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Careful mathematical treatment of this integral can extract the finite part with variables such that I can take the curl of. I have no idea what he did. But it works. The magnetic vector potential in the coulomb gauge is still obviously correct. but in the way I derived the final answer. No variables were present. Both are equivelant since they both are infinity. Yet one form is obviously better than the other HELP ME FIGURE OUT WHAT HE DID

Answer (score 0):

The symmetry of the setup means the $z$ derivative of any component of $\vec{A}$ is zero. The $r$ component of $\nabla \times \vec{A}$ is zero. One of the terms in the difference giving you the component is also zero since it's a derivative with respect to $z$. This implies the other term $\partial A_z/\partial\theta=0$.

By the above we know that $A_z$ is a function of $r$ alone. Specifically:

$$A_z=\frac{\mu_0I\ln{(C_1/r)}}{2\pi}$$.

So a potential with all other components zero and the $z$ component as above will give you the expected magnetic field.

Suppose we have $\nabla \times \vec{A}=\nabla \times (\vec{A}+\vec{Q})=\vec{B}$. It follows that $\nabla \times \vec{Q}=0$. By a theorem in vector calculus, this implies $\vec{Q}=\nabla f$ for some scalar function $f$.

So the question can become, does there exist an $f(r,\theta,z)$ so that when its gradient is added to $\vec{A}$ that removes the divergence without introducing a new one?

$$f=\frac{-z\mu_0I\ln{(C_1/r)}}{2\pi}$$

$$A_r=\frac{z\mu_0I}{2\pi r}=zB_\theta, \  A_z=A_\theta=0 $$

So, no longer diverges at large $r$. Now it diverges at large $z$ instead. And the $z$ dependence is weird, but doesn't seem to imply anything absurd about the field or the current distribution.

Not sure how to improve on that.